# Provide Validation for JavaScript Spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, spinner

I have a multiple column table with one of the columns being a checkbox. Whenever a checkbox is checked, it displays an extra column called `Quantity #` which contains a spinner where the user can either type in a number or use the up/down arrows to select a number. Currently, if you use the up/down arrows, it can go no lower than 1 and no higher than the quantity number associated with that row in the table.

However, for example, if the quantity is 80 and the user types in 85 themselves, then that will also be accepted. I do not want this accepted as you can not request 85 when there is only 80 quantity available.

So how can I provide validation to the spinner so that a user can not enter a number higher than the quantity number? Also, is there a way to make it so that the spinner will not allow any alphabetical characters and will only allow numerical characters?

HTML:

```
<section id="checkout-btn"> 
<button id="checkout" name="order" onclick="sendMail(); return false">Checkout</button>
</section>

<br>

<table id="merchTable" cellspacing="5" class="sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header">
            <th class="sorttable_nosort"></th>
            <th class="sorttable_nosort">Loc</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Report Code</th>
            <th class="merchRow">SKU</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Special ID</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Description</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Quantity</th>
            <th class="sorttable_nosort">Unit</th>
            <th style="display: none;" class="num">Quantity #</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row) {?>

        <tr>
            <td class="ui-widget-content"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check" id="checkid-<?php echo intval ($row['ID'])?>"></td>
            <td class="loc ui-widget-content" data-loc="<?php echo $row['Loc'] ?>"><input type="hidden"><?php echo $row['Loc'];?></td>
            <td class="rp-code ui-widget-content" align="center" data-rp-code="<?php echo $row['Rp-Code'] ?>" id="rp-code-<?php echo intval ($row['Rp-Code'])?>"><?php echo $row['Rp-Code'];?></td>
            <td class="sku ui-widget-content" data-sku="<?php echo $row['SKU'] ?>" id="sku-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU'])?>"><?php echo $row['SKU'];?></td>
            <td class="special-id ui-widget-content" data-special-id="<?php echo $row['Special-ID'] ?>" align="center" id="special-id-<?php echo intval ($row['Special-ID'])?>"><?php echo $row['Special-ID'];?></td>
            <td class="description ui-widget-content" data-description="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['Description']) ?>" id="description-<?php echo intval ($row['Description'])?>"><?php echo $row['Description'];?></td>
            <td class="quantity ui-widget-content" data-quantity="<?php echo $row['Quantity'] ?>" align="center" id="quantity-<?php echo intval ($row['Quantity'])?>"><?php echo $row['Quantity'];?></td>
            <td class="unit ui-widget-content" data-unit="<?php echo $row['Unit'] ?>" id="unit-<?php echo intval ($row['Unit'])?>"><?php echo $row['Unit'];?></td>
            <td style="display: none;" class="quantity_num ui-widget-content"><input type="textbox" style="width: 100px;" class="spinner" id="spin-<?php echo intval ($row['ID'])?>"></td>
        </tr>

    <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript for spinner:

```
$(function () {
    $(".check").change(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td.quantity_num').toggle(this.checked);
    console.log($('input.check').is(':checked'));
    var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.quantity').data('quantity');
        console.log(quantity);

  if($('input.check').is(':checked'))
    $(this).closest('table').find('th.num').toggle(true);
    else
    $(this).closest('table').find('th.num').toggle(false);



    $(this).closest("tr").find(".spinner" ).spinner({
      spin: function( event, ui ) {
        if ( ui.value > quantity ) {
          $( this ).spinner( "value", quantity );
          return false;
        } else if ( ui.value <= 1 ) {
          $( this ).spinner( "value", 1 );
          return false;
        } 

        var test = ui.value;
        sessionStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(test));
        var testtrue = sessionStorage.getItem("test");
        console.log(JSON.parse(testtrue));

      }
    });
  });
  });
```

JavaScript that gets info from a checked row and displays it in my email client once the "Checkout" button is clicked:

```
function sendMail() {
    var dataItems = [
        { 'clss':'.loc',         'prop':'loc' },
        { 'clss':'.rp-code',     'prop':'rpCode' },
        { 'clss':'.sku',         'prop':'sku' },
        { 'clss':'.special-id',  'prop':'specialId' },
        { 'clss':'.description', 'prop':'description' },
        { 'clss':'.quantity',    'prop':'quantity' },
        { 'clss':'.unit',        'prop':'unit' }
    ];
    var link = "mailto:me@example.com" + "?subject=" + encodeURIComponent("Order") + "&body=";
    link += $('#merchTable tr input[name="check"]:checked').closest('tr').get().map(function(tr) {
            var str = dataItems.map(function(item) {
                return encodeURIComponent($(tr).find(item.clss).data(item.prop)) + '\xa0\xa0';
            }).join('');
            str += encodeURIComponent($(tr).find('.spinner').spinner('value')) + '%0D%0A';
            return str;
        }).join('') + '%0D%0A';
    console.log(link);
    window.location.href = link;
}
```